# Why is it possible to measure just appended DOM element by a synchronous script?

Tags: javascript, dom, synchronous, event-loop

According to Event Loop basics and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0), re-render task is executing after all JS scripts have been completed. [The pixel pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPRMr.jpg)

But if synchronously add an element to the DOM and measure width or height, without waiting for a re-render - it works!
It's even possible to change element's content and measure again - still working.

So, why does this works?

```
let element = document.createElement('div');
Object.assign(element.style, {
  'position': 'absolute',
  'float': 'left',
  'whiteSpace': 'nowrap',
  'visibility': 'hidden',
  'font': '12px arial',
  'display': 'inline-block'
});

element.innerText = 'some text';
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(element);

// Why does it work? According to the video, 
// I need to wait when async render task be completed, isn't it?
console.log(element.offsetWidth);
```

Comment: also show what you tried and explain briefly so the members can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that the browser ordinarily batches changes to the dom and applies them all at once when the animation frame comes around. But if you ask for a value which depends on that rendering being complete (such as getting the width), the browser may be forced to immediately do a reflow in order to provide an answer to you. This should usually be avoided, since it can be a performance problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just tried to add an element and immediately stop on a breakpoint - I can see the element an it's sizes.